# Setting constants for a multi-domain sails.js website

Tags: sails.js

I have a website built using sails.js, which have multiple domain names pointing at it, and serving different content based on the domain name.

In order to store some constants, such as analytics ID, I created a policy to check for the host and set locals:

```
switch (req.get('host')) {
case 'domain-a.com':
  res.locals.googleAnalytics = 'UA-12345678-1';
  res.locals.siteName = 'Website A';
  res.locals.advertiserId = '12345';
  break;
case 'domain-b.com':
  res.locals.googleAnalytics = 'UA-12345678-2';
  res.locals.siteName = 'Website B';
  res.locals.advertiserId = '12345';
  break;
}
```

I wonder if there's a better to:

1. Store global variables
2. Check for the domain name

Thanks.